# Copy a component (combobox) with all properties into another components using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2010

I would like to know how to copy all the properties from a components to another component of the same type. I explain better:

I have a UI in Access 2010, and in the Form_Load() I set up the properties of all the combobox of my form like this:

```
For Each cCont In Me.Controls
       If TypeName(cCont) = "ComboBox" Then
           cCont.RowSourceType = "Value List"
       End If
Next cCont
```

Then I have different combobox where I add their information:

```
 cbUiUnit.AddItem "°C"
 cbUiUnit.AddItem "°F"

 cbTxUnit.AddItem "°C"
 cbTxUnit.AddItem "°F"

 cbUiUnit.DefaultValue = "cbUiUnit.ItemData(0)"
 cbTxUnit.DefaultValue = "cbTxUnit.ItemData(0)"
```

I would like to do this more automatic since every change on Units I need to do it twice. I could do another `For Each cCont In Me.Controls` as I did before, but the problem is that I have more than just these 2 combobox; all with different values.

I tried to do `cbTxUnit = cbUiUnit` after I set all the data of `cbUiUnit`, but It only copies `cbUiUnit.Value` into `cbTxUnit`. So all the added items doesn't exist in `cbTxUnit`.

Thanks

Comment: Some properties are 'read-only', so you can't copy 'ALL'. How many comboboxes need to be changed?

Comment: If I could copy the DefaultValue and the Added Items from one combobox to the other one I would be happy already. It's only 2 combobox `cbUiUnit` and `cbTxUnit` but main problem is that I need to change those units pretty often, depending on the choice of another combobox (weight, speed, temperature, distance...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a function to do this work for you

```
Private Function PopulateCombobox(inCbo as ComboBox) 
   inCbo.AddItem "°C"
   inCbo.AddItem "°F"
   inCbo.DefaultValue = inCbo.name & ".ItemData(0)"
End Function
```

Then you can call it like this

```
PopulateCombobox cbUiUnit
PopulateCombobox cbTxUnit
```

Then any changes you need to make can be universally applied and acer centrally located.

Comment: @EricPb you're welcome, I saw your edit and made a little change to it.